# stochastic process brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm not sure how to apply the Ito's calculus in the determination of an asset price at a given time T=t based on the Ito's lemma and a geometric brownian motion the asset price follows:

Assume: $S(t,X(t)) = S_0e^{ut + \sigma X(t)}$ given a known $S_0 = 100$, $u = .08$ and $\sigma^2 = .05$ and where $X(t)$ is a geometric brownian motion and $u$ and $\sigma$ are monthly parameters.

I can apply Ito's Lemma to compute $dS$

$dS/S = (u + \sigma^2)dt + \sigma dBt$

However I'm unclear how to compute S(t=3) given the monthly parameters.  How do I take into account the brownian motion X(t) to arrive at a value given $S_0$ = 100 at S(3)?

Comment: What do you mean by "compute $S(t=3)$" ?

Comment: I'm also uncertain as to what $dS/S$ is supposed to actually mean.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for the expected value $E[S(3)]$ or the expected value of the asset price at time t=3 given the brownian motion X(t).  I'm not sure how to arrive at a specific value of the asset price using geometric brownian motion, which to my understanding is N(0,t) normally distributed.

Comment: Ds/S is just the derivative of S(t,X(t)) assuming quadratic variance and application of Ito calculus